# M2Crypto causes a core dump

Tags: python, ssl, m2crypto

Any idea how I can fix this?

```
>>> from M2Crypto import SSL
>>> M2Crypto.version
'0.21.1'
>>> 

>>> ctx = SSL.Context()
>>> conn = SSL.Connection(ctx)
>>> conn.connect(('cancerhelp.org.uk', 443))
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the server can't handle the default `sslv23` protocol used by default by M2Crypto - at least it's part of the problem. It shouldn't segfault but give an error in this case, that's probably a bug in M2Crypto.

Try using `sslv3` or `tlsv1` instead:

```
from M2Crypto import SSL
ctx = SSL.Context(protocol='tlsv1')
conn = SSL.Connection(ctx)
conn.connect(('www.cancerhelp.org.uk', 443))
```

That worked for me...

Comment: Thanks that gets around the core dump.